# What is the difference between $\int v_i\,dt$ and $\int v_f\,dt$?

Tags: calculus, physics

I'm starting physics, and for a simple exercise, I wanted to derive each of the kinematic equations with calculus. I want to go from $v_f = v_i + at$ to $\Delta x = v_0t + 1/2at^2$, so I just integrated both sides of the first equation with respect to time, but I don't know what the difference between $\int v_i\,dt$ and $\int v_f\,dt$ is. Do they become two types of $\Delta x$?

Comment: $ v_i $ is the initial velocity (and thus constant) whereas $ v_f $ is the velocity as a function of time.

Comment: @talbi : So $v_i$ integrated with respect to time would be $tv_i + C$?

Comment: Yes. You can rewrite your first equation as $v(t)=v_0+at$, where $v_0=v(t=0)$